# htaccess to fallback to a base URL if page doesn't exist (404)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following scenario where in a CMS I have the following pages

`foo.com/jobs/2023/`  - base page listing jobs
`foo.com/jobs/2023/job-1` - single post with job on
`foo.com/jobs/2023/job-2` - single post with job on
`foo.com/jobs/2023/job-3` - this page returns a 404 response code

How would I go around redirecting the last link (which 404's) to `foo.com/jobs/2023/` but retain the first and second links going to the correct post.

I've tried the following however it was 500 erroring when I tested it on a dev server.

```
RewriteRule ^/jobs/2023/$ /jobs/2023/ [L,R=301]
```

Also done through PHP previously, though I need to do it at .htaccess level on a load balancer.

Current .htaccess file looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
## Redirect last years jobs to this years.
RewriteRule ^/jobs/2022(/?.*)$ /jobs/2023$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do `/jobs/2023/job-1` and `/jobs/2023/job-2` point to actual files or some controller? Can you post full .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava

They point to a controller in a Wordpress app. There's not much in the .htaccess at present, I'm just bootstrapping it today.

```RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/jobs/2022(/?.*)$ /jobs/2023$1 [R=301,L]```

Comment: This needs to be handled in Wordpress not in .htaccess. Only WP handler knows that a URL is 404